# How to remove defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

Recently, it was suggested to me to run this in my terminal:

`defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10`

but I have found that it is not helping my key strokes, but just adding one more annoyance to my work.

How do I undo this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete it using the command `defaults delete -g InitialKeyRepeat`.

I'm not quite sure what the original value is, so deleting it seems to be your best option. However, some [sources](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261163/default-value-for-nsglobaldomain-initialkeyrepeat) seem to indicate that `25` is the original value so you can try setting the value via `defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 25`.